# Is there an android application (or method) which can increase the display size for all other apps?

Tags: android, accessibility

Looking to see if there's an existing method or application to increase display size for all applications for people with bad vision.

Thanks!

Comment: By "increase display size", do you mean "increase magnification level"?

Comment: John, for the most part.  Buttons and text made larger to be more easily readable.  I guess "display size" could be interpreted to mean the actual screen size, which is not what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment this seems to be an on-going issue, but sadly there are no found solutions yet.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, if I were to be creating a suite of applications, would it be possible to create an inherited Activity class which was able to affect the view component sizes within it?  At least for the apps in that suite some measure of this capability would exist.

Comment: Adam, it is not something I have experience in but the concept sure seems plausible. When I get back from work, I can help out to see if any examples exist.